# Palindrome- while loop instead of for loop

Tags: python, python-3.5, palindrome

So my program checks for the number of palindrome numbers, lychrels, and non-lychrels. Originally I used a 'break' and a for loop, but I was supposed to use a while loop.

---

My while loop does not work the same as my for loop and I dont know what i did wrong? 
-- The range is meant to be between num1 and num2
also, the output is meant to be an exact copy of the prompt, so thats why it looks like this. 
Thanks!

Comment: Since the existence of Lychrel numbers has never been proved, how do you intend to count them?

Comment: Why not use a break in the while loop? Could you clarify your question? What exactly isn't working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while loop:

```
while (nums>=num1 and nums<=num2 and flag):
#for nums in range(num1, num2+1):
    num_str = str(nums)
    if num_str == num_str[::-1]:
       pal += 1
    else:
        count = 0
        num_el = num_str
        while (count < 60):
            np_total = int(num_el) + int(num_el [::-1])
            count += 1
            nums_el = str(np_total)
            num_el = nums_el
            if num_el == nums_el [::-1]:
                nonlych += 1
                flag = False

        else:
            lychrel += 1
            print(nums, "looks like a lychrel number")
nums += 1
```

The
`else:
    lychrel += 1
    print(nums, "looks like a lychrel number")`

is executing every time the `while` loops exits. The `break` in your `for` loop was skipping it.

Second problem is that when `flag` is set to `False`, it will stop your outer `while` loop, so the first non-lychrel number you find will be the last number you test.

Here's my attempt at changing as little as possible. You can add a flag like `isLychrel` instead of using the `count` variable to pass information.

```
nums = num1
while (nums>=num1 and nums<=num2):  
   num_str = str(nums)
   if num_str == num_str[::-1]:
       pal += 1
    else:
        count = 0
        num_el = num_str
        while (count < 60):
            np_total = int(num_el) + int(num_el [::-1])
            count += 1
            nums_el = str(np_total)
            num_el = nums_el
            if num_el == nums_el [::-1]:
                nonlych += 1
                count = 999 # breaks while loop

        if (count != 999):
            lychrel += 1
            print(nums, "looks like a lychrel number")
    nums += 1
```